# Getting GET instead of a POST on form submit

Tags: python, forms, post, get

The python code starts a web server, and it has these web pages of interest:

1. index.html : This contains an HTML Form which takes username and password
2. configure.html : This page should be called with POST username & password when form of index.html is submitted

.

```
import ubinascii
import utime
import socket
import select


html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> <title>Ouroboros IoT Login</title> </head>
    <body>
        <form action="configure.html" method="POST">
            Username : <input type="text"  name="username"></br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" ></br>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
"""

# Find out the post parameters in a dictionary
def get_post_params(req):
    print("Inside  POST PARAMS : req = " + req)
    post_params = req.split('\r\n')[-1:][0]
    # Check if the post body contains the necessary fields
    # Split the post_params by &
    # params : ['username=', 'password=', 'method=POST', 'url=http%3A%2F%2Ftwig-me.com%2Fv1%2Fusergroups%2FWKMUYXELA9LCC', 'jsondata=', 'submit=submit']
    print("post_params : " + post_params)
    params = post_params.split('&')
    print("Params")
    print(params)
    # Initialize the key value pair dict
    post_dict = {}
    # Iterate on each param
    for param in params:
        # Each param would be like 'method=POST', etc
        key_val = param.split('=')
        print("Key Val :")
        print(key_val)
        key = key_val[0]
        val = key_val[1]
        # Update post_dict
        post_dict[key] = val
    return post_dict

# This web server takes care of the WiFi configuration
# max_run_sec 
def web_server(max_run_sec = None):
    # Create server socket
    addr = socket.getaddrinfo('0.0.0.0', 80)[0][-1]
    s = socket.socket()
    # TODO : If both the wifi and sta are operating simultaneously, then bind only to WiFi
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(addr)
    s.listen(1)
    poller = select.poll()
    poller.register(s, select.POLLIN)
    startTimeEpoch = utime.time()

    while True:
        all_events = poller.poll(200)  # time in milliseconds
        if len(all_events) > 0:
            try:
                print("Just after GC Collect!")
                gc.collect()
                #print("Just before accepting")
                res = s.accept()
                client_s = res[0]
                client_addr = res[1]
                req = ''
                req = client_s.recv(4096)
                req = req.decode()
                req = str(req)
                # Came here means that there has been some connection!
                # Reset the start time epoch in such a case:
                startTimeEpoch = utime.time()
                # Check route now
                if req.find('configure.html') != -1:
                    print("Got configure request!\r\n")
                    # Check if the username and password are correct, if not, configure:
                    login_config = get_login_config()
                    username = login_config['user']
                    pwd = login_config['password']
                    print("Username : " + username + ", pwd : " + pwd)
                    # Find the POST PARAMETERS sent
                    # There would be just one entry in the array, so get the 0th index directly
                    # post_params : 'username=&password=&method=POST&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjam-me.com%2Fv1%2Fusergroups%2FWKMUYXELA9LCC&jsondata=&submit=submit'
                    post_dict = get_post_params(req)
                    # Now check if the post_dict has the key and value for username and password as needed?
                    username_post = post_dict['username']
                    password_post = post_dict['password']
                    # Check if the password is same as expected
                    if (username_post == username) and (password_post == pwd):
                        hidden_input = '<input type="hidden" name="username" value="' + username + '"><input type="hidden" name="passphrase" value="' + pwd + '">'
                        # Send the login username and password inside the hidden input field
                        configure_html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> <title>Ouroboros IoT WiFi Configuration Page</title> </head><body><form action=\"configure_wifi.html\" method=\"POST\">WiFi SSID : <input type=\"text\"  name=\"essid\"></br>WiFi Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"passphrase\" ></br>" + hidden_input + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" name=\"submit\"></form></body></html>"
                        # TODO : Also show link to webpage, where from we can change the login credentials
                        client_s.send(configure_html)   
                    else:
                        client_s.send(login_fail_html)
                elif req.find('configure_wifi.html') != -1:
                    # Check if the username and password are correct, if not, configure:
                    login_config = get_login_config()
                    username = login_config['user']
                    pwd = login_config['password']
                    # Get post parameters
                    post_dict = get_post_params(req)
                    # Now check if the post_dict has the key and value for username and password as needed?
                    username_post = post_dict['username']
                    password_post = post_dict['password']

                    # Check if the password is same as expected
                    if (username_post == username) and (password_post == pwd):
                        # Do some sanity check for handling the new wifi ssid and password
                        new_wifi_ssid = post_dict['essid']
                        new_wifi_passphrase = post_dict['passphrase']
                        # Set the wifi credentials
                        save_wifi_config(new_wifi_ssid, new_wifi_passphrase)
                        client_s.send('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> <title>Ouroboros IoT WiFi Configuration Success</title> </head><body>Configuration successful!<br>Device would go into reboot now!</body></html>')
                        # Reboot device now
                        machine.reset()
                    else:
                        client_s.send(login_fail_html)
                elif req.find('index.html') != -1:
                    print("Got index.html request!\r\n")
                    client_s.send(html)
                else :
                    # Do nothing
                    print("Invalid request received! Show the login page again!\r\n")
                    client_s.send(html)

            except OSError:
                # Got no request and it timedout!
                print("Timed-out, no request received!\r\n")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Got some exception\r\n")
                print(str(e))
            finally:
                client_s.close()
                if max_run_sec is not None:
                    elapsedTime = utime.time() - startTimeEpoch
                    if elapsedTime >  max_run_sec:
                        # Max run time of web server has elapsed, time to exit this mode!
                        break
    # Unregister poller
    poller.unregister(s)
    # When while loop ends!
```

When I access index.html, everything works ok, the web page appears. However. when I click on submit after typing in admin/admin, instead of a POST, I get a GET request on web server, whose content is as follows:

```
Inside POST PARAMS : req = GET /configure.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/65.0.3325.181 Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

Weirdly, instead of a POST, I'm getting a GET. Can anyone find the obvious mistake? I'm using Chromium web browser on Ubuntu, ESP8266 micropython.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. At the least, you've got `</br>` closing tags that don't match any open tags. (You probably wanted a self-closing `<br />`?) There may be other errors, but once you've got unbalanced tags like that, all bets are off for how a browser will parse things and interpret the results.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert: I'll check if what you're saying could cause such a big problem.

Comment: Also, technically, `method="POST"` is not valid in HTML5; it needs to be `method="post"`. However, that one, I doubt any actual browser would care about.

Comment: Meanwhile, after changing the URL to an absolute one (so I can capture the result with an `nc`), even without fixing the error,  Chrome 66 on Mac and Chrome 65 on iOS and Android all make a `POST` request for me. So do Safari 11.1 and Firefox 59 and 60. So… can you actually reproduce this with the HTML you pasted here?

Comment: I'll try in couple hours. I thought the same about post vs POST. I'll try both changes and inform you.

Comment: @abarnet: can you post your code for my reference please

Comment: I just copied your HTML, changed the `action` from `configure.html` to `http://10.11.23.100:12345/spam`, saved it, and opened it in a bunch of browsers. For the server, I have no code at all—I just did `nc -kl 12345` on `10.11.23.100` so I could quickly see what each browser sent.

Comment: @abarnert: I did the same thing with nc, with my original code, and it does send POST from my ubuntu chromium browser. Wonder why the code did not work when the server was running on ESP8266, and index.html was opened on this ubuntu chromium browser.. Any thoughts what may have happened?

Comment: Can you repeat it? Are you sure you’re looking at the submit rather than the initial load? (It’s not sending form data as query params…)

Comment: Removing </br> and making post in small case solved the problem. Also provided the entire URL in action (http://192.168.0.1/configure.html).. Dont know which helped exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your HTML is invalid, enough so that it's forcing the browser into "guess what I mean mode", and the browser is apparently confused enough to guess badly wrong.

I can't actually reproduce the problem on a variety of different Chrome, Safari, and Firefox browsers on macOS, iOS, and Android—they all properly send a `POST`. But an unmatched tag error is exactly the kind of thing that could cause this kind of problem.

In particular, you have two `</br>` tags, which are closing tags for a `<br>` that you never opened. Most likely this was just a typo or thinko for `<br />` (a self-closing tag).

You also may have another error. In HTML5, while attribute names are always case-insensitive, not all attribute values are. I'm pretty sure HTML 5.2 explicitly requires *enumerated* attributes to do ASCII-case-insensitive matching, but IIRC, HTML 5.0 left it unspecified. If so, and if your browser is not up to date, technically it could legally treat `POST` as an invalid value and use the invalid-value default of `get`, instead of treating it as `post`. I'm not actually sure this is true—and, even if it is, I can't find a browser that actually behaves that way, and can't imagine any would have a good reason to do so, so I doubt this is your problem. But still, no reason not to get it right.

So, the fix is to change your HTML to this:

```
html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> <title>Ouroboros IoT Login</title> </head>
    <body>
        <form action="configure.html" method="post">
            Username : <input type="text"  name="username"><br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" ><br />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
"""
```

More generally, you should always validate your HTML—either using an external validator, or just by using the developer tools built into almost every browser. If you see HTML errors or warnings, fix them—especially if you're also seeing inexplicable behavior, but even if you aren't.